# Angularjs: change object property of specific index of nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've nested ng-repeat like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(dayOfWeek, time) in uiHoursOfOperation track by $index" ng-init="daysOfWeekIndex=$index">

 <div class="" ng-repeat="openCloseSet in time.uiDayMs track by $index">
    <md-input-container>
      <md-select ng-model="openCloseSet[0]" ng-init="openTime = openCloseSet[0]">
        <md-option ng-repeat="uiTime in time.avaiableTime" ng-value="uiTime.msValue">
        {{::uiTime.display}}
        </md-option>
      </md-select>
     </md-input-container>

    <md-input-container ng-if="$index === 0">
      <md-button ng-click="addSplitHours(time.uiDayMs ,$index +1, time)">
         Add                                      
      </md-button>
    </md-input-container>
 </div>

</div>
```

On clicking the **Add** button. It creates a new block of `time.uiDayMs`.

Here is the add function:

```
$scope.addSplitHours = addSplitHours;
function addSplitHours(index, time) {
    var newOpen = time.uiDayMs[time.uiDayMs.length - 1][1] + 900000;
    time.uiDayMs.push([newOpen, newOpen + 900000 * 4]);

    var closingtimeStarts = closingTime + 900000;
    var closingtimeEnds = avaiableClosingTimes[avaiableClosingTimes.length - 1].msValue;
    for (
        var msValue = closingtimeStarts;
        msValue <= closingtimeEnds;
        msValue += 900000
    ) {
        time.avaiableTime.push({
            msValue: msValue,
            display: moment(msValue)
                .utc()
                .format("h:mm A")
        });
    }
}
```

You can see I'm taking the next index number but unable to use it.
So my main question is how can I make the `time.avaiableTime.push` to only that specific index? Currently, It changes on each `time.avaiableTime` but I wanted to push on that specific index only.

Comment: You have passed two arguments only to addSplitHours function, first parameter index value must be coming as uim days because of which you are not able to access the index and your question is not very clear either create a plunker or show the running snippet and as per your question answer it is possible to change the object property of particular index.

Comment: Here is the working Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/8oxhWtdY7si8lAdOC7kP?p=preview

If you click add it'll create a new block. And on the 2nd block, I wanted to do time.avaiableTime.push so it creates a new list of time